# Disabled trackbacks in Wordpress but I am still receiving trackbacks

Tags: pingbacks

I have disabled trackbacks in Wordpress back end discussion panel but I am still receiving trackbacks. How can I ensure that I do not receive any trackbacks?

Answer (score 5):

Changing the global Trackbacks setting via `Dashboard -> Settings -> Discussion` will only change the *default* behavior. If you currently have existing posts/pages with trackbacks *enabled*, changing the default setting will not change the per-post setting.

You will need to go to `Dashboard -> Posts`, select all posts, and batch-edit them to disable trackbacks. (Then repeat with Pages.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition with Chip Bennett's answer you can programmatically unapproved Trackback comments using this filter:

```
 add_filter('pre_comment_approved',function($approved,$comment){
        
    if( in_array($comment['comment_type'],array(
            
        'trackback',
        'pingback',
        
    ))){
        
        $approved = false;
    }
        
    return $approved;
        
},999999,2);
```

**Reference**

https://code.recuweb.com/2023/stopping-wordpress-trackback-spam-without-plugin/